# Center values at comma

Tags: excel

so I was exporting a correlation matrix from python to excel and now have positive/negative values with or withuot stars e.g.
-0,12*
0,07
0,33***
-0,57***
0,22**
-0,17**
-0,01
How can I center these values at the comma? Does anyone know the correct custom format I need to enter?

I tried to find out which custom format to use but was not successfull.

Comment: please define "center", provide some screenshot so we can understand what is the input and the expected output.